# Strange issue in running Remote Desktop after installing a MUI package

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, remote-connection

I have a machine with Windows 7 Professional SP1. I wanted to change to S.O. language from Portuguese to English, but due to the fact that I wasn't running an Ultimate version of Windows, I wasn't able to install a MUI package directly from Windows Update.

So that I downloaded by myself a package used Vistalizator in order to install the English MUI package.

The problem is that now I'm getting the following error when I invoke Remote Desktop:

```
The system cannot find the specified file
C:\Windows\System32\<LANG_NAME>\mstsc.exe.MUI
```

Is there a way to fix that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I discovered that I needed to install the following update packages on my Windows 7 machine:

- `Windows6.1-KB2574819-x64.msu`
- `Windows6.1-KB2592687-x64.msu`

After that, `mstsc.exe` command became functional again.

Comment: it didnt fixed mine :'( my os came from Japanese to English MUI, installed both updates but still didnt work.